# black and white image prints purple-ish when transparency is changed in InDesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, transparency

I have a black and white jpg placed on the page in InDesign CC. I'd like it to be a faint image behind text, so I changed the transparency to 20% but it prints with a purple-ish hue. I edited the graphic in PhotoShop by changing the saturation to 0, and it prints gray from PS but when I bring it back into ID and print, its purple hue is back. It looks good when I print it in grayscale, but I have other color images in this file that need to be printed in color.

Comment: Printing to what? What's the color mode of the image? What's the InDesign blend space set to?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem. You are placing a color image (RGB/CMYK) image in InDesign which looks like a B&W image.

By desaturating it in Photoshop you are ensuring neutral colors, but InDesign doesn't analyze each pixel in the image to check if it *looks* like a B&W image. It still just sees it as an ordinary color image.

So when converting to CMYK (which is happening behind the scene when printing) your B&W image is separated into all four process colors like any other color image.

This method is not ideal for B&W images since it requires a perfect balance between the CMYK inks to create a neutral result. Only perfectly calibrated equipment can do this and there will always some kind of color tint.

Furthermore, if your image is in CMYK mode, setting the opacity to 20% can add to the problem because the balance between the CMYK colors needed to make a neutral color isn't necessarily the same at 20% tint as at 100% tint.

To make a long story short, the simplest everyday solution is to convert every image which is supposed to look B&W to **grayscale** in Photoshop.